# How to initialize the fields of a structure inside of an array of pointers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create data structures that would help to store a dictionary with words and their definitions.

At first, I have defined the following structures that describe entry in the dictionary and structure of the dictionary itself, respectively:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{

   char wordInDictionary[32];
   int numberOfMeanings;
   char *wordDefinitions[10];

}Entry;

typedef struct{

   int entries;
   Entry *arrayOfEntries[10000];

}Dictionary;
```

As the next step, I should have created the empty dictionary with 0 entries. Here is what I had an attempt on:

```
Dictionary createDictionary(){

   Dictionary emptyDictionary;

   emptyDictionary.entries = 0;

   int i, j;

   for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
       emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->numberOfMeanings = 0;
       strcpy(emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordInDictionary, "\0");
       for(j=0;j<10;j++){
           strcpy(emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordDefinitions[j], "\0");
       }
   }

   return emptyDictionary;

}
```

However when I test it in **main()** it shows that there is ***segmentation fault: 11***:

```
int main(){
   Dictionary dict = createDictionary();

   printf("%s", dict.arrayOfEntries[0]->wordInDictionary);
   printf("%i",dict.entries);
}
```

How could I fix the issue so that I would return a dictionary with 0 entries?

Comment: The pointer `emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]` is uninitialized, you can't `emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->` dereference it. Where should `emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]` __point__ to? If you are starting with programming, that it is strange that a dictionary has 10000 pointers to entries, wouldn't it be simpler if a dictionary would just have the entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[]` is a statically initialized array containing 10000 pointer to ... nothing.

The first line in `createDictionary()` creates the 'Dictionary' item as a stack variable. The array inside is uninitialized. With many compilers it will contain NULL pointers. But assume it even contains garbage.

As soon as you touch `emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[0]->...` in the first iteration of your for-loop, you are dereferencing that pointer. (using `->` on it. That is the point of the crash.

You need to fill those first by allocating an Entry first.

```
#define DEFINITION_SIZE 40

.....

for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
       // first allocate the entry before touching it.
       emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i] = (Entry*)malloc(sizeof(Entry*));
       emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->numberOfMeanings = 0;
       strcpy(emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordInDictionary, "\0");
       for(j=0;j<10;j++){
           // first allocate this item as well
           emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordDefinitions[j] =
                   (char*)malloc(DEFINITION_SIZE);
           strcpy(emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordDefinitions[j], "\0");
       }
   }
```

But there are a few problems:
 - The structure is huge. 10000 entries, each containing another array of 32 chars and 10 pointers.
 - The returns statement in `createDictionary()` copies and returns the structure (shallow copy).